# Sitecore.Mvc.Analytics exception For A/B Testing

Tags: sitecore, sitecore-analytics, sitecore8.2

I'm trying to perform a simple A/B test.
There is a layout that has only one placeholder.

```
<div>
    @Html.Sitecore().Placeholder("main") //breakpoint here which throws exception
</div>
```

Then there is a view rendering (called Section) with a datasource that has to load inside the placeholder. By default, `Section` is assigned a datasource item `Text1`. I can view the desired result in Experience editor.
Now, I add another variation, by just changing the datasource for the same rendering to `Text2`. I can see in the floating box, the two variations and the text being changed when manually changing the variations.
I click on Save and try to open the page again in Experience editor and there is this exception.

> An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in
>   Sitecore.Mvc.Analytics.dll but was not handled in user code

I am unable to view this page in Experience editor now after adding the second variation.
The page is assgined the sitecore's Sample workflow. I have also added Sitecore.Analytics.dll & Sitecore.Mvc.Analytics.dll to the Visual Studio solution.

How to fix this?
Using Sitecore 8.2 with VS2015

**Error Log**
I checked the error log which at a point says something about the layout. The layout exists and other pages using the same layout work fine. The problem occurs after adding a second variation and viewing in exp. editor. It works ok when viewing in preview mode !!

Here is the log recorded. Hope it tells something......

```
ManagedPoolThread #11 10:40:21 INFO Job ended: Sitecore.ListManagement.Analytics.UnlockContactListsAgent (units processed: )
12968 10:40:28 ERROR Application error.
Exception: System.Web.HttpUnhandledException
Message: An unhandled exception occurred.
Source: Sitecore.Mvc
at Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.MvcEvents.Exception.ShowAspNetErrorMessage.ShowErrorMessage(ExceptionContext exceptionContext, ExceptionArgs args)
at Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.MvcEvents.Exception.ShowAspNetErrorMessage.Process(ExceptionArgs args)
at (Object , Object[] )
at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
at Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.PipelineService.RunPipeline[TArgs](String pipelineName, TArgs args)
at Sitecore.Mvc.Filters.PipelineBasedRequestFilter.OnException(ExceptionContext exceptionContext)
at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeExceptionFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, Exception exception)
at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName)
at Sitecore.Mvc.Controllers.SitecoreActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName)
at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<>c__DisplayClass22.<BeginExecuteCore>b__1e()
at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.<.cctor>b__0(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Action action)
at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState)
at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
at Sitecore.Mvc.Routing.RouteHttpHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result)
at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)

Nested Exception

Exception: System.InvalidOperationException
Message: Error while rendering view: '/Views/CampaignLayout.cshtml' (model: 'Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.RenderingModel, Sitecore.Mvc').

Source: Sitecore.Mvc
at Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.ViewRenderer.Render(TextWriter writer)
at Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.RenderRendering.ExecuteRenderer.Render(Renderer renderer, TextWriter writer, RenderRenderingArgs args)
at Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.RenderRendering.ExecuteRenderer.Process(RenderRenderingArgs args)
at (Object , Object[] )
at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
at Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.PipelineService.RunPipeline[TArgs](String pipelineName, TArgs args)
at Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.RenderingView.Render(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer)
at System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)
at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)
at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)
at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult)
at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName)

Nested Exception

Exception: System.NullReferenceException
Message: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
Source: Sitecore.Mvc.Analytics
at Sitecore.Mvc.Analytics.Pipelines.Response.CustomizeRendering.SelectVariation.GetTestCombination(Item variableItem, Item contextItem, ID deviceId)
at Sitecore.Mvc.Analytics.Pipelines.Response.CustomizeRendering.SelectVariation.GetVariation(Item variableItem, Item contextItem, ID deviceId)
at Sitecore.Mvc.Analytics.Pipelines.Response.CustomizeRendering.SelectVariation.Evaluate(CustomizeRenderingArgs args)
at (Object , Object[] )
at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
at Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.PipelineService.RunPipeline[TArgs](String pipelineName, TArgs args)
at Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.PipelineService.RunPipeline[TArgs,TResult](String pipelineName, TArgs args, Func`2 resultGetter)
at Sitecore.Mvc.Analytics.Pipelines.Response.GetRenderer.CustomizeRendering.Process(GetRendererArgs args)
at (Object , Object[] )
at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
at Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.PipelineService.RunPipeline[TArgs](String pipelineName, TArgs args)
at Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.PipelineService.RunPipeline[TArgs,TResult](String pipelineName, TArgs args, Func`2 resultGetter)
at Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.Rendering.GetRenderer()
at Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.Rendering.get_Renderer()
at Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.Rendering.ToString()
at Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.RenderRendering.InitializeProfiling.StartProfiling(RenderRenderingArgs args)
at Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.RenderRendering.InitializeProfiling.Process(RenderRenderingArgs args)
at (Object , Object[] )
at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
at Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.PipelineService.RunPipeline[TArgs](String pipelineName, TArgs args)
at Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.RenderPlaceholder.PerformRendering.Render(String placeholderName, TextWriter writer, RenderPlaceholderArgs args)
at (Object , Object[] )
at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
at Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.PipelineService.RunPipeline[TArgs](String pipelineName, TArgs args)
at Sitecore.Mvc.Helpers.SitecoreHelper.Placeholder(String placeholderName)
at ASP._Page_Views_CampaignLayout_cshtml.Execute() in c:\inetpub\wwwroot\democore\Website\Views\CampaignLayout.cshtml:line 45
at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy()
at System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy()
at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage)
at System.Web.Mvc.Html.PartialExtensions.Partial(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, String partialViewName, Object model, ViewDataDictionary viewData)
at Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.ViewRenderer.Render(TextWriter writer)



12968 10:40:28 INFO Cache created: 'Log singles' (max size: 100KB, running total: 2297MB)
12968 10:40:28 WARN Page extenders were not added, because an error occurred during the request execution
ManagedPoolThread #6 10:40:31 INFO Job started: Sitecore.ListManagement.Analytics.UnlockContactListsAgent
ManagedPoolThread #6 10:40:31 INFO Job ended: Sitecore.ListManagement.Analytics.UnlockContactListsAgent (units processed: )
ManagedPoolThread #7 10:40:41 INFO Job started: Sitecore.ListManagement.Analytics.UnlockContactListsAgent
ManagedPoolThread #7 10:40:41 INFO Job ended: Sitecore.ListManagement.Analytics.UnlockContactListsAgent (units processed: )
```

Comment: Do you have a stack trace from the log file?

Comment: Is there anything within the view (CampaignLayout.cshtml) like a @Model.SomeProperty that is null in the one variation and not in the other?